# While designing a software, what are the criterion used to partition that software into indivisual components?

Tags: design, software, engineering, component

Good software is always designed based on different modules before integration. I was wondering what rules/guidelines decide software partition into different, smaller modules during the design phase.

Comment: usually, experience. Sometimes, random guesses. The latter way usually ends up being a problem.

Comment: The main guideline is that software modules should align with the underlying conceptualisation - the things and relations that exist abstractly, and which would be expressed in natural language when explaining to others. As for guidelines on how to conceptualise things, that's really not easy to boil down!

Comment: Keywords here are coheshion and coupling. Ideally, cohesive modules should have low coupling between each other. This means that "APIs" between modules are as generic and as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

### Names

The most important thing a component can have is a good name. One that makes clear what does and doesn't belong inside. Doing this ensures people can find things and keep them organized.

### Behavior

Most components do something. Components that do similar things tend to hang out together. Components that do many things tend to get broken up into more components. A component should have a clear point to it. That point is easy to make when all the things the component does are about the same sort of thing.

### Coupling

Imagine software as a fish net. Look at it closely in any one spot and sometimes you'll see a simple straight string going off in two directions. Sometimes you'll see a knot where many strings are tied together. The art of choosing components can be seen as putting the walls of your components where they cross simple straight strings and not knots.

Oh sure there are many more forms of [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). But this is the one that most impacts components. In fact [components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_component) (an idea and name that predates OOP) turn out to be an ideal place [hold these knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxman).

### Structure

This is what most people obsess on. Which usually ends tragically when done while ignoring what I listed above. Structure can tie you up or provide flexibility. But while it's a good servant it's a poor master. Letting structure make decisions for you is a good way to paint yourself into a corner. Always be willing to restructure to make a code change easy. Do not kill yourself trying to make every problem fit into some existing structure.

Answer (score 0):

Completion.

A large project is usually in a constant state of fixes and improvements. It can never be completed. But, small parts of it often have a limited scope of functionality and can be completed.

If you can separate those parts, complete them, move them out to another repo and consume them via a package manager or similar then you never have to look at their code again.

This reduces the size of the large project and makes it easier to maintain.

If you have this in mind as you develop you will see which parts have, or are likely to have a well defined scope and which don't. Try and make everything into parts with well defined scopes and gradually complete and move them out.